# Couldn't find log file upon monaca preview failed

Tags: monaca

I'm getting error when run my monaca-cli, "monaca preview"

`Failed to transpile: Error has occured while transpiling /Users/geohu/Codings/essMobile/essmb with webpack. Please check the logs.`

However, I couldn't figure out where should I check the logs.